# How to handle exceptions from a BackgroundWorker thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

In a WPF app I have a sheduled database access task, periodically run by a timer and this task have been executed in a BackgroundWorker thread.

When connection attempt failed I raise an exception by `try_catch` construction and I want to update a Status Bar text in a UI thread.

Is there some prebuild event construction in a `BackgroundWorker` for implementing this, something like `DoWorkEventHandler` or `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler`, which can be used for this? If not, how to do it better?

**Edited (added):**

If I want to handle the exception inside `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler`, using `e.Error` parameter, it doesn't work. In case I leave exception unhandled in the `BackgroundWorker` thread, application hangs on and debugger points to the string of code which is excuted inside `BackgroundWorker` thread, saying that: ***Exception was unhandled by user code***.

So, in this case, thread doesn't just stop, signalling to `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler` that it stopped with error, but the whole application stop working.

Comment: Thanks to all for answering! Taking into account some answers, I updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A WPF UI can be updated from a background thread by using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

For example if your background code was part of a Window then you could update a TextBlock:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        textBlock.Text = "Connection Failed!";
    }));
```

Edit:

If your background code were in a class other than your Window you could make an interface to help:

```
public interface IShowStatus
{
    void ShowStatus(string message);
}
```

Implement the interface in your Window

```
public void ShowStatus(string message)
{
   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
       {
           textBlock.Text = message;
       }));
}
```

In your class with the background worker make a property to hold a reference to the interface.

```
public IShowStatus StatusDisplay { get; set; }
```

In your Window class initialize the background class.

```
public void InitBackground()
{
    BackgroundClass background = new BackgroundClass();
    background.StatusDisplay = this;
    ...
```

Finally in your background thread you can say:

```
StatusDisplay.ShowStatus("Connection Failed!");
```

Comment: In my case the background code is not part of a Window but it runs inside a separate class. Moreover, exception takes place in a static method. So, THIS keyword is not valid in this case. PLease, help me understand, how I could reference my main UI window in this case?

Comment: I added notes in reply to your question.

Answer (score 7):

The `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e` of the `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler` contains property `Error` it is of type Exception. If no exception occurred during the work of the background thread the prpery has null as value. Else it contains the error that occurred.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     Exception exceptionThrowDuringDoWorkEventHandler = e.Error;
}
```

Comment: When I try to throw an exception from the BackgroundWorker thread, the app just crashes with: Exception was unhandled by user code. I never get to bw_RunWorkerCompleted. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Set the **WorkerReportsProgress** property of the background worker to **true**, then add an event handler for the event **ProgressChanged**. In the following code, I added an event handler for Form.Load also.

Now try the following code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.UserState.ToString());
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //some code that throws an exception
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0/*percent of progress*/, ex);

            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to handle the exception inside
>   `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler`, using `e.Error` parameter, it
>   doesn't work. In case I leave exception unhandled in the
>   `BackgroundWorker` thread, application hangs on and debugger points to
>   the string of code which is excuted inside `BackgroundWorker` thread,
>   saying that: ***Exception was unhandled by user code***.
>
> So, in this case, thread doesn't just stop, signalling to
>   `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler` that it stopped with error, but the
>   whole application stop working.

I'm very curious about this. Try running the following code in a console app and see if your program crashes or if the error shows up in the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += Bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += Bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Complete.");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
    }

    private static void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```